# i have an error connecting my project to Mongodb , how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
 I keep getting a MongoDB connection error when I try to connect to my MongoDB`enter code here`.
```

here is the error from my commandline

```
 ok: 0,
```

code: 8000,
codeName: 'AtlasError'

Comment: I would double check that your Atlas instance allows connections from the IP you are connecting from. It will be in the Atlas security settings.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first connection to the MongoDB, are you sure you inserted the right connection string?

Does the password to your username contain special characters?